# Allow typing only autocomplete values in Textbox

Tags: c#, winforms, autocomplete

I want to allow only typing autocomplete values in Textbox, I tried making code for KeyPress event but unfortunately it seems to take long time when I have a huge AutoComplete list.
Here is my code :

```
private void TBAdd_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        bool found = false;
        List<string> list = ((TextBox)sender).AutoCompleteCustomSource.Cast<string>().ToList<string>();
        int i = 0;
        while (!found && i < list.Count)
        {
            if (list[i].Contains(((TextBox)sender).Text + e.KeyChar))
            {
                found = true;
            }
            i++;
        }
        e.Handled = !found;
    }
```

Is there any other optimized way for doing this ?

Comment: Is this a web application?  If so, why don't you use some JavaScript?

Comment: Nope its WinForms application.

Comment: Do you already have auto-complete functionality where the user can see the possible values?  Then you might be better off saving the validation until the user is done with their input.  Assuming they are clicking a button or doing some action after they have entered input in the text box.

Comment: Have a look at [FastColoredTextBox](https://github.com/PavelTorgashov/FastColoredTextBox).

Comment: "Only AutoComplete Values" - you want to limit the user choices? Maybe you can consider using a dropdown `ComboBox`?

Comment: If you really need to validate every keypress, you might consider moving the processing to another thread.  At least it wont lock up your UI.